# Loop Counter not working

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set /a eng_aud_count=0
set /a eng_sub_count=0

For /f "tokens=1-9 usebackq delims=.:^)^( skip=2" %%A in ("MY text File") do ( 

set trck=%%B
set lang=%%C
set type=%%D

If "!type!"==" Audio" (
IF "!lang!"=="eng" (
set /a eng_aud_count+=1
)
)

If "!type!"==" Subtitle" (
IF "!lang!"=="eng" (
set /a eng_sub_count+=1
)
)

set default=no

If "!trck!"=="0" (set default=yes)

IF !eng_aud_count!==1 (set default=yes)
IF !eng_sub_count!==1 (set default=yes)

Echo !trck!---!lang!---!type!---!default!--!eng_sub_count!
)

Exit /b

Endlocal
```

Result:

```
0---eng--- Video---yes--0
1---eng--- Audio---yes--0
2---eng--- Audio---no--0
3---spa--- Audio---no--0
4---fra--- Audio---no--0
5---deu--- Audio---no--0
6---por--- Audio---no--0
7---eng--- Audio---no--0
8---eng--- Subtitle---yes--1
9---spa--- Subtitle---yes--1
10---spa--- Subtitle---yes--1
11---fra--- Subtitle---yes--1
12---fra--- Subtitle---yes--1
13---dan--- Subtitle---yes--1
14---nld--- Subtitle---yes--1
15---fin--- Subtitle---yes--1
16---deu--- Subtitle---yes--1
17---deu--- Subtitle---yes--1
18---nor--- Subtitle---yes--1
19---por--- Subtitle---yes--1
20---por--- Subtitle---yes--1
21---swe--- Subtitle---yes--1
22---eng--- Subtitle---no--2
```

What I want to do is make first eng audio to default=yes, and also make first eng Subtitle to default=yes.

Using the above script I am able to make first eng/audio default=yes but when I go to do the same for eng/subtitle it breaks. Every track after first eng/subtitle gets set as default=yes when it should be set to default=no.

Need some help.

Thanks.

Comment: -1 you should troubleshoot this and try to figure out what BATCH FILE ISSUE it is. You should eventually break it down to a simple problem. Trying to demonstrate an issue of a loop counter not working does not require a reference to 'Encoded.mkv'

Comment: And if I do `for /r %a in (a.a) do echo %a` then I get an error `(a.b) was unexpected at this time.`  As it's meant to be a directory there not a file. So perhaps you could clarify how your line `For /r %%A in (*Encoded.mkv) do (` is meant to work,

Comment: The outer loop should not be there, update code.

Comment: Can you be much more clear, by, pasting the results you want, and contrast it with the results you get. Don't just describe, as your english is poor.  You pasted the results you get, that's good. But also paste the results you want.  Also try to explain in English what 'default' is meant to represent. Also consider whether you want to say `IF !eng_aud_count!==1`   or  if you want to say `IF !eng_aud_count!>=1`

Comment: Also you write "Every track after first eng/subtitle gets set as default=yes when it should be set to default=no"  That's not true even in your own results. The last line of your results is `22---eng--- Subtitle---no--2` and you're not clear whether you want it to be yes or no. Also I suggest you write a flowchart to help you understand your code.

Comment: I just have hard time writing my thoughts into word. As I said I want the first eng audio to have the value "yes", any track number after that eng audio would have value of "no", which is working correctly.  But when I apply the same logic to the subtitle it breaks. First eng subtitle has a value of "yes" but any subtitle track after also has a value of "yes", which it shouldn't. I just want the first eng subtitle to have value of "yes".

Comment: you also made it difficult for people because they'd have to write up your data file 'cos you didn't include it. And many programmers can't understand explanations that well anyway and need code. And you should still have pasted the results as you wanted them. Anyhow I think I understand what you mean. My code gives the results that I think you want.

Answer (score 1):

I can see why. But i'd like you to see how you can see why.

I created a file with lines like

```
g:0:eng:Video
g:1:eng: Audio
```

That essentially mirrors your file %%B is track  %%C is lang  %%D is type

I wasn't sure initially why the program was doing wrong. But then I added these lines-

```
echo eac=!eng_aud_count!
echo esb=!eng_sub_count!
pause
```

Now you should see what your program is doing, and why it works for Audio and not for Subtitle.

```
C:\crp>a
0---eng---Video---yes--0
eac=0
esb=0
Press any key to continue . . .
1---eng--- Audio---yes--0
eac=1
esb=0
Press any key to continue . . .
2---eng--- Audio---no--0
eac=2
esb=0
Press any key to continue . . .
3---spa--- Audio---no--0
eac=2
esb=0
Press any key to continue . . .
4---fra--- Audio---no--0
eac=2
esb=0
Press any key to continue . . .
5---deu--- Audio---no--0
eac=2
esb=0
Press any key to continue . . .
6---por--- Audio---no--0
eac=2
esb=0
Press any key to continue . . .
7---eng--- Audio---no--0
eac=3
esb=0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

^^^^^^^^^ ALL THAT IS OK

```
8---eng--- Subtitle---yes--1
eac=3
esb=1
```

^^^^ THAT IS GOOD

```
Press any key to continue . . .
9---spa--- Subtitle---yes--1
eac=3
esb=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

^^^^^^^ THERE IS THE PROBLEM see the esb is wrong from the point of view of the logic of your program. And keep pushing any key to continue, see esb is 1. In your program's logic, esb=1 (english subtitle count == 1) means you are at the first one and you want default=yes for the first one and only the first one. But of course, esb isn't going to reflect that. Because when you hit later subtitles, french, spanish, whatever, your count is still going to be 1.

The whole logic of your program has to be rethought, because it's not based on count that you want to do it, or not just on count. It has to be
a)when it hits the first subtitle/audio
b)the first time it hits it

I added 2 new variables. eng_aud_flag and eng_sub_flag

There are a load of statements that echo stuff which I used to find mistakes I made while rewriting the logic of the program. I have left those statements in there REMd out, so you have an idea of how to debug

At one point I wondered why some code wasn't executing, so I put an echo statement there saying GOT HERE, and then I found out why it wasn't executing, and fixed it. I then no longer need that echo but I left it there REMd out so you have an idea how to debug things.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set /a eng_aud_count=0
set /a eng_sub_count=0

set /a eng_aud_flag=false
set /a eng_sub_flag=false

For /f "tokens=1-9 usebackq delims=.:^)^( skip=2" %%A in ("a.a") do ( 

set trck=%%B
set lang=%%C
set type=%%D

set default=no


If "!type!"==" Audio" (
  IF "!lang!"=="eng" (
  set /a eng_aud_count+=1
  IF !eng_aud_count!==1 (
    set /a eng_aud_flag=true
    set default=yes
  )
 )
)

If "!type!"==" Subtitle" (
IF "!lang!"=="eng" (
set /a eng_sub_count+=1
REM echo here
REM echo eng_sub_count==!eng_sub_count!
 IF !eng_sub_count!==1 (
 REM echo GOOD
  set /a eng_sub_flag=true
  set default=yes
 REM  echo here2
 )
)
)



If "!trck!"=="0" (set default=yes)


Echo !trck!---!lang!---!type!---!default!--!eng_sub_count!



 REM echo eac=!eng_aud_count!
 REM echo esb=!eng_sub_count!
REM  echo def=!default!
REM echo subflag=!eng_sub_flag!
REM echo audflag=!eng_aud_flag!
REM  pause
)

Exit /b

Endlocal
```

---

```
C:\crp>type a.a


g:0:eng:Video
g:1:eng: Audio
g:2:eng: Audio
g:3:spa: Audio
g:4:fra: Audio
g:5:deu: Audio
g:6:por: Audio
g:7:eng: Audio
g:8:eng: Subtitle
g:9:spa: Subtitle
g:10:spa: Subtitle
g:11:fra: Subtitle
g:12:fra: Subtitle
g:13:dan: Subtitle
g:14:nld: Subtitle
g:15:fin: Subtitle
g:16:deu: Subtitle
g:17:deu: Subtitle
g:18:ryt: Subtitle
g:19:por: Subtitle
g:20:por: Subtitle
g:21:swe: Subtitle
g:22:eng: Subtitle


C:\crp>
```

---

```
C:\crp>a
0---eng---Video---yes--0
1---eng--- Audio---yes--0
2---eng--- Audio---no--0
3---spa--- Audio---no--0
4---fra--- Audio---no--0
5---deu--- Audio---no--0
6---por--- Audio---no--0
7---eng--- Audio---no--0
8---eng--- Subtitle---yes--1
9---spa--- Subtitle---no--1
10---spa--- Subtitle---no--1
11---fra--- Subtitle---no--1
12---fra--- Subtitle---no--1
13---dan--- Subtitle---no--1
14---nld--- Subtitle---no--1
15---fin--- Subtitle---no--1
16---deu--- Subtitle---no--1
17---deu--- Subtitle---no--1
18---ryt--- Subtitle---no--1
19---por--- Subtitle---no--1
20---por--- Subtitle---no--1
21---swe--- Subtitle---no--1
22---eng--- Subtitle---no--2

C:\crp>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. This works. I worked on the batch script further, one thing was that I needed to nested the if statements more. I was able to remove the additional variables that you added and still get the result that I wanted. **I know how the programmers love the "shall statements" in requirements, where it does not illustrate what the customers actually wants. :)**